# Opted into YouTube HTML5 trial; all videos displaying Flash?

Tags: youtube, html5

I have opted into the HTML5 trial and going to the page still says I'm opted in. It used to work great and it would only display Flash for the old videos without HTML5 conversion. A few weeks ago it stopped working, and every video I watch is Flash. This happens in the newest Firefox, but I also tested it in Chrome and it still happens.

How do I watch YouTube videos in the HTML5 player?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn?hl=en ?